# Casper.js links from array

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, casperjs

Help me, how to go to the URL of the array? The problem is that the list of URL getting going from another pages (casper), and is initially unknown. Example:

```
casper.thenEvaluate(function() {
    var links = new Array;

    $('.ValueBets > li').each(function() {

           links.push($(this).find('.MDxMatchLink').attr('href')); 

    }); 

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess (didn't prove it) one of the problems is that you define your array inside the evaluate, anyways i can give you this solution for you problem (getAllHref):

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var url = "yourTargetUrl";
var links;

function getAllHref() {
    var hrefs = casper.evaluate(function() {
        return Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll('a'), function(e) {
            return e.getAttribute('href');
        });
    });
    return hrefs;
}
casper.start(url);
casper.then(function() {
    // statements
    links = getAllHref();
});
casper.then(function() {
    // show all links at once
    casper.echo(JSON.stringify(links));

    // show single hrefs
    while (links.length > 0) {
        link = links.pop();
        (function(link) {
            casper.then(function() {
                casper.echo('link: ' + link);
            });
        })(link);
    }
});
casper.run();
```